# Can I build an Eclipse RCP Application with some plug-ins in the "dropins" folder?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

As mentioned in the title, when I build an Eclipse RCP Application, can I place some plug-ins in the **dropins** folder ?

Or I could only **manually** place some plug-ins in the **dropins** folder after the building is complete ?

Comment: emm... the plug-in in the **dropins** folder will be moved to **plugins** folder ?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I have some plug-ins which may most likely change in the furure.   Some plug-ins may be deleted, some plug-ins's dependency may be changed, the features which some plug-ins belong to may be changed...   so I do not want to use feature to manage these plug-ins, I think it is diffcult for p2 to manage feature like this.  The solution I can think of is to manage them in dropins folders.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the concept of features as they are exactly for what you want. A product is made up of features. A feature can contain plugins and other features. A higher version of a feature can contain a different set of plugins and features, or even an older version of some plugins. Using the `dropins` folder does not provide benefits, it just requires more disk space and slows down the start-up. How do you build your RCP application without features? This doesn't sound like the recommended way of building with Tycho.

Comment: Since the possibility and extent of my features changes are very large, I think it is likely that there will be problems when I update them through p2 "Check for Updates", so I want to manage them through dropins folder.

I have a question, why do you say that "requires more disk space" to use **dropins** folder?  If use dropins, all plug-ins are in dropins folder, while if use feature, plug-ins are in **plugins** folder and there will also be some feature files in the **features** folder, which will take up more disk space.

Comment: The `dropins` folder is a p2 thing. The same requirements applies to both cases, installing a plugin via `dropins` folder or via an update site. The only difference is that via `dropins` folder no feature is needed, but it is treated as if there is a feature that contains the plugins of the exact version. The `dropins` folder is scanned on start-up and if there are new things, they will be installed and if there are removed things, they will be uninstalled. So the disc space of the `dropins` folder is required in addition.

Answer (score 1):

The `dropins` folder is just a temporary location for plug-ins that the Eclipse p2 update system will look at to find new plug-ins to install in the main `plugins` folder. You can't put anything there during a build.

`dropins` is intended as a last resort way of installing new plugins - ideally new plug-ins should be installed using "Install New Software" from a properly built update site or repository so dependencies can be checked properly.

Note that if your RCP doesn't include the p2 update system none of this will work.